# Retrieving and checking a password in JAVA from a CSV file

Tags: java, email, csv, passwords

I need to code a program in which:
Asks for an email adress and password,
Searches a csv file for the email adress (Just call the csv file x),
If the password is correct it displays the customer details,
It displays a error message if the password is incorrect.

Comment: regardless of the vague question: do not store pasword in a csv file !

Comment: sounds easy, prompt email&password, find matching entry in your file (csv is normal text file, so read line from it is not quantum physics) display maching line or error message

Answer (score 2):

It is insecure to store the plain text password in a CSV file where at least system administrator can easily see it. Use the security grade one way hashing like SHA or similar, store the hash code in CSV file and compare the hash codes instead.